# Cut a string in two groups in bash

Tags: bash

Lets say I have this string:

```
A single (very ugly) tree (Outdoor treks) 2.
```

I wanna split it in 2 groups: the first one contains the substrings that are not in `()`, and the second one the last substring that is in `()`

1stGroup:

```
A single tree 2
```

2ndGroup:

```
Outdoor treks
```

Comment: Can the parenthesis be nested? What is the supposed result look like, if the input is `a`b (c (d e) f ( g h)) i`? Also, post your own attempt to solve the problem, so that we can see where you got stuck.

Comment: Nope they cant be nested

Comment: And you  have always exactly two parenthese groups in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ firstGroup=$(sed 's/\([^(]*\)([^)]*)/\1/g' input_file)
$ secondGroup=$(sed 's/.*(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/' input_file)
$ echo "$firstGroup"
A single tree 2.
$ echo "$secondGroup"
Outdoor treks
```